# Special Characters in a Variable

Tags: variables, batch-file, character

I have searched for an way to pass on the special characters located in a string but cannot find anything relevant. Currently the string is concatenated at the first special character.

```
for /D /R "%cd%" %%d IN (*) do (call :Write_File "%%~nd")
```

Can escape character be used or will I need a for loop to substitute the special characters, and another to replace them?

The variable is supposed to return the folder name. It returns the full length string unless it contains a special character %, &, ,, ., etc.
at which point it returns everything up until that point. Example B&B returns B, where as I require it to return B&B.

With three example folder named: "%$", "01, Copy" and 03&

echoing the variable as it reads it (&&echo "%%~nd"): "$%", "01, Copy" and misses the third
Renaming the variable within :Write_File (set "FOLDER=%~1"): "$", "01, Copy"

**Edit for clarification:**

Special Characters: %, $, &, *, ~, etc.

Use: When echoing the folder names
Sometimes it misses the special character, sometimes it skips the folder entirely.

Comment: I can't see your special character :/

Comment: What special characters? What string? What concatenation? - You have not provided enough information to allow others to help.

Comment: And, furthermore `for /D /R "%cd%" in ...`  dosn't make sense. You can remove the `"%cd%"` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `CALL` here with the value, instead use a reference to a variable.

```
for /D /R %%d IN (*) do (
  set "myDir=%%~nd"
  call :Write_File myDir
)
exit /b

:Write_File
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "param1=!%1!"
echo !param1!
endlocal
exit /b
```

Comment: Yay! It worked, thanks a lot. I was expecting it to also miss the last folder as it is not within the delayed expansion. Thanks again!